# Querying UMLS (Unified Medical Language System)

Tags: library, data-analysis, health

I am looking for a library or program that would allow me to programmatically query [UMLS](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/), mostly retrieving parents and children of an entity as well as searching most entities in the semantic network, either from the RFF files directly or from an MySQL database. If possible, a Python library and open source. [PyMedTermino](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMedTermino) looked promising but has some issues and the implementation is not completed (e.g. no search function yet).